# Socketio not connecting on postman socket connection ui on localhost

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, postman, localhost

```
Could not connect to localhost:3000
17:02:53
Error: Unexpected server response: 404
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

My express server listen on 3000 port and socketio http on 443 port, i am able to connect socket by hosting this on ec2 instance and using ec2 ip with port number on postman socket connection ui, but on localhost connection always failed with above error on postman socket beta ui.

Comment: Is your server running on `localhost` or the "localhost's" ip? THe server need to surely run on  "localhost" as hostname.

Comment: I was tried to connect socket with localhost:3000 as socket url in postman

Comment: Please show the code how you start your express server.

Comment: Please see the answer section for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `listen` only once. If you pass your `http/https` server to express, `app.listen()` is enough. (except you want to listen on 2 different ports.. For testing, let's call it only once.)

For accessing it on `localhost` try setting it explicitly with the parameter `hostname` in `app.listen()`.

#### Example:

```js
async function startServer() {
  const app = express();

  const credentials = {key: key, cert: crt};
  const httpsServer = createServer(credentials,app);
  const io = socketIO(httpsServer);
  
  await require('./loaders').default({ expressApp: app, socketIO: io });

  // Let's only call listen once for testing purposes. If you call 
  // listen on the express app, your https server will automatically listen 
  // to the same configuration.
  // httpsServer.listen(4000);

  
 
  const port = 3000
  const hostname = 'localhost'
  // explicitly let the app listen on localhost. If hostname is not 
  // provided, it will take the first found ipv4 interface
  app.listen(port, hostname, err => {
    if (err) {
      Logger.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
      return;
    }
    Logger.info(`
      ################################################
      ️  Server listening on https://${hostname}:${port} ️ 
      ################################################
    `);
  });

}
```

Now you should be able to connect your socket. If it still does not work try
to use `http` module instead of `https` for better isolating your problem.

Note that your server now only will be accessible using `localhost` and not over ip. Both may only be possible when running 2 server instances with different hostnames.

Comment: if this issue is related to usage of listen twice, how this work on ec2 linux instance

Comment: IT is related to the `hostname` parameter. If you do NOT explicitly pass `localhost` as hostname to your `listen` function then you are not able to access it via `https://localhost` .................................... Please read the answer again. I Commented out one `listen` for being sure, that we point to the correct url .

Answer (score 0):

```
async function startServer() {
  const app = express();

  const credentials = {key: key, cert: crt};
  const httpsServer = createServer(credentials,app);
  const io = socketIO(httpsServer);
  
  await require('./loaders').default({ expressApp: app, socketIO: io });

  httpsServer.listen(443);
  app.listen(config.port, err => {
    if (err) {
      Logger.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
      return;
    }
    Logger.info(`
      ################################################
      ️  Server listening on port: ${config.port} ️ 
      ################################################
    `);
  });

}
```

This is my app.ts file, I am using Ubuntu. so 443 port is not allowed, i changed this port to 4000, now the app listen on the 3000 and socket http server on 4000, but socketio not able to connect with socket url localhost:3000